# HTML: <code> heightens block box - any remedies to get it back in vertical rhythm?

Tags: html, css, tags, inline, baseline

I'm currently getting my block- and inline-elements into a vertical rhythm (baseline pattern).

Most of my inline-elements do well and stay in their inline box, bowing themselves to my line-height.  Most do so, but a little village of stubborn Gauls - called the <code>-tag.

I let jquery tell me padding (0), margin (0), border (0) and line-height (as expected) - all seems right (whereupon padding, margin and border shouldn't have any effect on the baseline of an inline element anyways). But unfortunately: The code tag extends my technical inline box (block container), why the following lines of text are translated down one or a few pixels.

```
<code>
    some code
</code>
```

Writing this question, it appears that stackoverflow itself got this problem managed, as `some code` isn't disrupting the baseline. Stackoverflow uses e.g. css: p code {padding: 1px 5px;}, but it even works here when I disable this or other styles, why I can't derive a solution for my problem.

Anyone an explanation or any elixir to normalize the <code> Gaul? p.s.: It's not on my normalize.css - got no preformatting for this tag yet. Applying the preformats of Bootstrap (Gallagher) doesn't solve this either. My doctype is <!DOCTYPE html>.

Comment: Please show a code example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Thx for your interest. Got a solution in the meantime (see edit).

Comment: There appears to be a real problem involved, but it was not presented in the question: no code that reproduces it. Setting `line-height` probably affects something in a complex environment where it overrides some other settings. – You should edit the question only to clarify what the problem is. An answer should be posted as an answer, *after* there is an answerable question, and if possible with a demonstration of how it works.

Comment: 1. Thought a code example might be a bit trivial (<code>some code</code>). 2. Complex environments may be not affected, as the code tag is an inline element which mostly would be used at the end of the DOM, therefore not affecting too much other elements. 3. Ok, shifted the solution into an own answer. Thx

Comment: The code is not trivial. The phenomenon depends on font family, too, so you should either set it in the code or specify which fonts you tested with. And you should show code that actually demonstrates the issue and tell what to look at in the rendering.

Answer (score -1):

Solution found: Set your css standardize/normalize to ...

```
code
{
    line-height:normal;
}
```

The kbd and samp tags need this too. Although the line-height was inherited correctly before (and had the same height as other elements), code, kbd and samp seemed to be shifted somehow. The above setting makes them stay in baseline (Problem appeared in Firefox 35.0). Setting line-height to zero works too... whyever.

Comment: Since `normal` is the initial value of `line-height`, there must be some setting that you are overriding if this works.

Comment: Actually theres neither a declaration of line-height or font before nor after (!important) that affects line-height. The problem may be browser specific. However.. problem solved.